Azure Traffic Manager Endpoint: The following locations specified in the geoMapping property for endpoint are not supported
I'm trying to create an Azure Traffic Manager Endpoint via Terraform, but I don't know what to put in "geo_mappings" value. This is my resource:
resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_azure_endpoint" "se22condary-ae" {
  name                = "se22condary-endpoint"
  profile_id           = azurerm_traffic_manager_profile.tm.id
  target_resource_id  = azurerm_linux_web_app.secondary.id
  geo_mappings         = ["Europe"]
}

And I have this error:
Error: creating/updating Endpoint Type (Subscription: "xxx"
│ Resource Group Name: "ist-platform-geodev2"
│ Traffic Manager Profile Name: "ist-traffic-manager-geodev2"
│ Endpoint Type: "AzureEndpoints"
│ Endpoint Name: "s22econdary-endpoint"): endpoints.EndpointsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadRequest" Message="The following locations specified in the geoMapping property for endpoint ‘s22econdary-endpoint’ are not supported: EUROPE. For a list of supported locations, see the Traffic Manager documentation."
│
│   with azurerm_traffic_manager_azure_endpoint.se22condary-ae,
│   on main-geodev2.tf line 475, in resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_azure_endpoint" "se22condary-ae":
│  475: resource "azurerm_traffic_manager_azure_endpoint" "se22condary-ae" {

It seems that the Azure documentation is not updated and I can't find values. I tryed with "Europe" "EU" "North Europe", but problem still

Check my answer.

thank you, but I solved and mine still valid. Is pretty the same thing

You can use the Geographic Hierarchies - Get Default endpoint or run the following Azure CLI command to get the list of country/region codes:
az network traffic-manager endpoint show-geographic-hierarchy

From the output we can see that the code for Europe region is GEO-EU:
{
  "geographicHierarchy": {
    "code": "WORLD",
    "name": "World",
    "regions": [
      {
        "code": "GEO-EU",
        "name": "Europe",
        "regions": [
          {
            "code": "AD",
            "name": "Andorra",
            "regions": []
          }

     // rest of content here
}


the response is similar to the mine one. And you have to set up it manually before. Still valide but is the same

@GiacomoBrunetta no, it's not similar. There's no need to create an endpoint manually to get the corresponding value. And what do you mean by set up it manually before? You're using Terraform to manage the resources, so you need to know the valid values for geo_mappings one way or another. If you need to create endpoints using Terraform in 20 different regions do you prefer to run the command to list the codes or creating these 20 endpoints manually and then get the codes from the portal?

ahhh ok I see! So, you find the solution. Thanks

I've found the solution.
I created manually the resource on Azure and then I used this command:
 az network traffic-manager endpoint list     
    --profile-name ist-traffic-manager-geodev2     
    --resource-group ist-platform-geodev2

to retrieve information about the endpoint I created manually. The syntax is: "GEO-EU"
{
    "alwaysServe": "Disabled",
    "endpointLocation": "North Europe",
    "endpointMonitorStatus": "Online",
    "endpointStatus": "Enabled",
    "geoMapping": [
      "GEO-EU"
    ],
}

For instance, if you want to put North America you will write "GEO-NA"
